# How to copy a very large video file with error in it?

Tags: linux, hard-disk, usb-drive, file-copy

I have a very large video file on a USB external hard disk. It is about 13GB. I can play the video directly, and it seems there's no problem. But if I try to copy the file to other places, I got a strange error and the USB device is disconnected automatically, then connect back again.

I tried copying from KDE, using *cp*, or *rsync*, no luck. I am running out of ideas. I have never seen this kind of problem before.

P.S.

- The file is on a LVM partition.
- I don't have the error message now. But I remember it was some like

> Failed to read block ...

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Can you add `dmesg|tail -n 20` or other logs from syslog?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try your luck with `ddrescue`. It's usually used for whole disks or partitions, but it also works with single files. It keeps a logfile for retries.

```
ddrescue /source/your_video.avi /target/your_copy.avi /target/your_copy.logfile
```

If the disc vanishes in this process, just remount it and start the command again, and it should resume where it left off.

`ddrescue` also has a bunch of options, use `info ddrescue` for a manual and more detailed usage examples.

If you have a disk to spare, making a whole disk copy might give better results. It depends on what's damaged exactly - the file itself or just filesystem metadata.

Comment: Right. This is when it *does* make sense to have your defective drive partitioned somehow. :) Because this will make the (raw) partition *images* significantly smaller. If the HDD is 1 TB and you were using the whole 1 TB as one primary partition, you will have to get your hands on a destination HDD with a little more than 1 TB of *continuous* free space to put it onto. And this is not always as easy as it sounds...

Answer (score 2):

Your drive is likely failing. You should see messages to this effect in your `dmesg` log. I would attempt to repair the disk with either [HDAT](http://www.hdat2.com/download.html) (freeware) or possibly [Spinrite](http://www.grc.com/spinrite.htm) (Commercial). I've used both of these tools to recover disks that were failing and they have both worked well in the past.

Additionally you can check the drive's SMART info:

```
$ smartctl --all /dev/{hd?,sd?}
```

This won't fix anything but will let you know if there is something up with the health of the drive.

Once the drive is in a usable state I'd use [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/) to replicate it as quickly as you can to an alternate HDD, or get that one video file off of the HDD.